# How to shift nested object to the outer object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to move object into the outer object's contained nested object?

```
{ criteria: 
   { provider: 2,
     providerName: 'CLX_gw0',
     mcc: null,
     mnc: null,
     dial_code: null,
     active: 1 },
  page: 1,
  pageSize: 50 }
```

I want like this:

```
{
    provider: 2,
    providerName: 'CLX_gw0',
    mcc: null,
    mnc: null,
    dial_code: null,
    active: 1,
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 50 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you simply want that someone else works for you?

Comment: You'll have to create the object manually.

Comment: i tried to use flatten/flattenDeep but this for array only? i guessed to be some method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  You don't even need lodash:

```
const newObj = Object.assign({}, obj, obj.criteria);
delete newObj.criteria;
```